# Comparing two independent variables (one numeric, one categorical) against one categorical independent variable? ag

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chemometrics

Sorry if this question is a repeat. I'm new to R, and writing up a chemistry-focused meta-analysis (in collaboration with a statistician, but they're on holiday until November).

I have three variables at play here: the concentration of chemical A (a range from 0 to 10 molar) and the presence of chemical B  (yes/no) vs the final structure of the sample (which fits into categories - e.g., bcc, fcc etc).

I've managed to plot it, and just by looking at it you can see that there are differences, but I'm not sure how to statistically quantify it. I've looked online and stackoverflow, but there are so many tests and I don't have the stastistical understanding to pick a suitable one. If I was given a hint or pointed in the right direction, I feel I could figure the rest out (until at least I meet again with the statistician).

To clarify: I know that the concentration of A influences the final structure, I want to see if the presence of chemical B suppresses this effect.

Comment: Greetings! Maybe you can post the plot and some information about your data. Its a bit difficult to answer the question as is as there isn't a lot answerers can go off of.